# Need to restrict the multiselect picklist

Tags: apex, picklist, validation-rule, page-layout

I have AccountContactRelation and role is the multiselect picklist field.
Based on Type i need to show or allow users to select picklist values.
EX:  Role values:-P1,P2,P3,P4,P5
If type="Active" User can select or can see only P1,P3,P5
If type="InActive" user can select or can see only P2,P4
Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Assuming AccountContactRelation is a custom object. You can create field dependencies on Type and Role field.

Comment: No Type is not on accountocontact relation object .Type is  Account object field

Comment: Can you be more clear on what field is on which object you are trying for and describe the problem?